# Abrir en nueva ventana variable con una pagina html rellenada dinámicamente por Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un formulario muy extenso que se envía por ajax:

```
function submitform() {
    var data= $('#wizardform').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        url : './DAO/crearestudio.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data : {
            data : data
        }
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log("click en finalizar")
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("no se puede enviar")
    })
}
```

Luego en `crearestudio.php` recibo los datos y relleno una web html con los datos generados y la meto en una variable:

```
$body='   <tr>
                <td>Gastos repuestos media por vehículo año</td>
                <td>'.$jsonestudio[16]["value"].'</td>
            </tr> esto es un ejemplo porque el html tiene 600 lineas';
```

He intentado guardarlo como archivo PDF pero no me sale como quiero, se me rompe el estilo. Entonces he pensado en imprimir esta variable por la impresora o guardarla de alguna manera ya que si hago un `echo $body;`, Sí se muestra el contenido correctamente.

---

¿Como puedo imprimir esa variable, o que se me muestre en el navegador esa web? Ayuda por favor, estoy atascado, Gracias de antemano

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. ¿Por qué en el `done` de Ajax no modificas el DOM, mostrando lo que quieras mostrar o creando lo que quieras crear. Y si lo que quieres es generar un PDF, quizá es mejor hacerlo desde el servidor. En fin, el planteamiento de tu pregunta es algo confuso.

Comment: yo simplemente quiero que imprima en pdf o por impresora o descargue o algo, con la pagina html que se genera por ajax, si me meto en la consola de desarrolador de chrome, en network, me genera perfecto el archivo que quiero generar pero yo quiero que me lo muestre en pantalla... no en network o que lo descargue en pdf o algo pero que se vea. Me entiendes? PD: Gracias por contestar

Comment: Te entiendo. Eso lo puedes hacer sea en el mismo servidor, sea en Ajax, en la parte `done`. Sería en cualquier caso devolver el texto que tendría el archivo y generarlo.

Comment: podria poner en crearestudio.php un return($body) y que en el .done lo imprima por ejemplo con .printThis()?

Comment: Exacto, podrías retornar `$body` desde el servidor, recuperarlo en el cliente, en la parte `done` de Ajax y ahí imprimir o generar el PDF.

Comment: voy a intentarlo muchas gracias mantengo activo hasta que pruebe

Comment: Ten en cuenta que, desde cualquier lado que decidas generar el PDF (cliente o servidor) es muy probable que necesites una librería adicional para ello.

Comment: del lado del servidor estoy utilizando dompdf pero el informe lo tengo generado con bootstrap y no me lo genera correctamente, mas o menos si pero no me respeta la relacion de aspecto y en html si me lo respeta, la variable $body que tiene el html dentro me si hago un echo, me genera el informe perfectamente, por esta razon queria imprimir desde la variable

Comment: Eso ya es cuestión de ajustar la librería para que reconozca ciertas cosas que son propia de los estilos CSS y demás. No tengo experiencia usando librerías que generen PDF y no sé si son mejores las de PHP o las de Javascript para eso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes recibir ese HTML como respuesta a tu llamada `POST`, solo tienes que hacer `echo $body;`, en javascript recibes esa info en la parte `done` de ajax justo en la variable response. Con esos datos abres una ventana con [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) y escribes el response dentro de la ventana con document write.

Recuerda que muchos navegadores bloquean las ventanas emergentes y es posible que tengas que permitirlas explícitamente para que funcione correctamente.

```
function submitform() {
    var data= $('#wizardform').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        url : './DAO/crearestudio.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data : {data : data}
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        let nuevaVentana = window.open('', "NuevaVentana", "");
        nuevaVentana.document.write(response);
        nuevaVentana.print(); //para enviar a la cola de impresión            
        console.log("click en finalizar");
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("no se puede enviar")
    })
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias lo hace casi perfecto!, lo unico que sera fallo de alguna parte del codigo que se queda cargando en bucle y hasta que no le doy a "X" (Paro la carga) no se me imprime